# Did the American Evangelical Church Excommunicate Ted Haggard after his shenanigans?

Tags: evangelicalism

Wikipedia says:

> On November 3, 2006, Haggard's resignation of leadership of the National Association of Evangelicals was accepted.

But my question is:

- Did the American Evangelical Church excommunicate Ted Haggard after his shenanigans?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Excommunication refers to a church putting a person outside of their *communion* - in less jargony terms we could say that it refers to declaring that a person is no longer a member of a church.

The National Association of Evangelicals is an inter-denominational fellowship of over 40 denominations and 45 thousand individual congregations. The NAE is not a church, so it does not make sense to talk about being excommunicated from the NAE. Ted Haggard's personal church could have potentially excommunicated him, but not the NAE. It seems that his old church, New Life Church, fired him and required him to leave the area, which I think is akin to being excommunicated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no formal group that reviews misdeeds and excommunicates people from church. So, no, Ted Haggard was not excommunicated by any such body. I doubt that the National Association of Evangelicals excommunicated him, either.